# How do I tell Ninject not to inject one of my constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

If I have the following:

```
public MyClass(IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo, IServiceThree serviceThree = null)
{
  this.serviceOne = serviceOne;
  this.serviceTwo = serviceTwo;
  this.serviceThree = serviceThree ?? new ServiceThree("some-info");
}
```

How can I tell Ninject to bind the first two arguments, but not the one of type IServiceThree? Is this even possible?

The reason I want serviceThree as a constructor argument is for testability - I need to be able to inject a mock from my tests.

Comment: This is a design smell. You should never allow injecting `null` into a constructor. Instead, you should simply inject a `ServiceThree` instance into the constructor. IMO, Ninject should never had a `AllowNullInjection` property in the first place.

Comment: What about overloading your constructor with only two arguments and specifically marking that overload for NInject to use? `[Inject] public MyClass(IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't plan to use constructor injection then you might as well remove it from the constructor arguments list and initialize it manually the way you do it. In other words, just pass two arguments instead of three.

UPDATE: What you could do is to inject `null` value. As far as I remember you would have to do something like following:

```
_kernel.Settings.AllowNullInjection = true;
```

Then you can remove the binding for the third argument if it exists.

Comment: The reason I want it as a constructor argument is for testability - I need to be able to inject a mock from my tests. Sorry about that. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Still, you are using concrete implementation inside your constructor. Whatever you pass as the third argument will be ignored even inside your unit tests.

Comment: Sigh. This is what happens when you don't proof read a question. Sorry. I'm using a default value for the last parameter, so that I can either use the value injected from my tests or create a new instance. I've updated my question.

Comment: Could you actually explain under which circumstances you would want to prevent Ninject to bind to your third parameter. One way of doing it would be to remove the binding all together from the binding list.

Comment: Ninject actually tries to bind IServiceThree even when there is no binding set up in Ninject's NinjectWebCommon. (And obviously throws an error.) So in a nutshell, I never want Ninject to inject that particular parameter, but I still want it in my constructor so that I can inject a mock myself.

Comment: I just updated my answer. It's been a while since I used Ninject, but something like the above line could allow you to inject null value instead of an object.

Comment: Can't I do `AllowNullInjection` on one binding only instead of the whole kernel? Because doing this on the whole kernel has much impact...

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid setting `AllowNullInjection` globally while still injecting a parameter only when a binding exists by configuring your binding like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyClass>()
      .To<MyClass>()
      .WithConstructorArgument(typeof(IServiceThree), c => c.Kernel.TryGet<IServiceThree>());
```

Answer (score 0):

For testability you need to mock the interface you wish to behave as null (just doing nothing when you call its methods) and pass as a constructor parameter.

The way you're doing is wrong and you add testing code dependency into your production code.